# How long can you change your vote?

Tags: support, voting

I always thought that one can change a vote on a post only a few minutes unless it is edited.

So how could someone undo his vote on [that Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9582637/575376) today since no one upvoted or edited it today?
I am sure I'm just missing something.

[image: Rep Stat]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually, it's 5 minutes exactly. Here, there are 2 possibilities as to what could have happened:

1. Since you edited your post shortly after posting, someone could have upvoted within that initial 17 minute window, and decided to undo it later.
2. If someone with edit privileges *really* wants to undo their own locked vote, they can edit the post themselves, undo their vote, and then undo their edit. If this is done within the editing grace period, their edit disappears forever.

Comment: But I edited it 2 weeks ago and today the vote disapeared. Or do you mean one can change his vote forever if a vote was before an edit?

Comment: So it was option 2.

Comment: @Dennis: Ah now I got it. He can **undo** his edit.

Comment: No, there's no time limit between an edit and a vote. Merely between a vote and another vote (or a retraction). So even though two weeks past, if the original vote was prior to your edit, the voter would still have been able to retract it. And no, lunboks - it is *not* possible to completely hide an edit to a post by rolling it back within the grace period. In fact, rolling back an edit immediately creates a new revision and *ends* the grace period. [Ah, Dennis points out that you can - this is a bug.]

Comment: @juergend: Exactly. I'm not proud of it, but I have done exactly that a few times to correct an undeserving downvote. But option 1 is theoretically possible (albeit unlikely). You **can** change your vote forever if the post was edited.

Comment: @Shog9: Regarding your edit: That's not true. If you undo your edit within the grace period, it disappears from the revision history.

Comment: @Dennis: if this is true, it's a serious bug. Show me.

Comment: @Shog9: Notify me when you see the edit.

Comment: @Dennis: yes, I see the edit.

Comment: @Shog9: And now, you don't.

Comment: Ok, that's very bad, @Dennis. Please write it up!

Comment: @Shog9: [Done.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133301/undone-edits-disappear-from-revision-history)

Comment: @Shog9 This is quite old, and has been mentioned on meta many times in the past (usually in comments, but a couple of times in answers). Quite frankly, it's handy and will be missed

Answer (score 1):

Probably whoever had upvoted it *before* it was edited unupvoted it. Sounds unlikely, but possible. Why would they do that is beyond me... Unless--unless they're gunning for Electorate.

Badge fraud anyone?

Comment: I think if you unupvote the vote goes away, so it doesn't count towards Electorate.

Comment: ...Or they simply hadn't been back to the answer in that time, and upon revisiting it decided it wasn't worth the vote.

Comment: @yannis Electorate is for question votes. You also need them to be in a certain percentage of total votes. Hence the answer -1

Comment: @shog9 Yeah, though the post _was_ improved. And there's no _fun_ in saying that ;-)