# Unupvote when no change to a Q in weeks

Tags: discussion, voting, voting-limits

I've just (today) received a -5 (unupvote) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828191/integrating-a-web-crawler-into-a-net-app) (Previously +1/-1).

Putting aside for the moment if it *should* be voted up/down, can someone please explain to me how it's possible to un-upvote when the question hasn't been modified in any way since the 6th?

Was I mistaken in my understanding that an hour after voting, it's locked unless the Q is edited?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: It most certainly is. I see it recorded as "unupvote" and not "User was deleted"

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/156755/basic?tab=reputation), it clearly says "unupvote". If it was a deleted user, it would say "user removed".

Comment: Not at all. The rep line reads `-5 | 13 hours ago | unupvote | Q Title`. How can I tell? [Wow, too slow]

Comment: Yup, I forgot we could see those too and didn't look at the rep page at all..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [happened to me recently](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/390/869). This is related to a documented issue that [undone edits disappear from the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133314/167443).

So a user wanting to remove a locked-in vote on a post simply needs to edit it, remove the vote, and undo the edit (manually undo, not roll back).

Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133297/167443

Comment: Either that, or the user who unupvoted (sic!) was Jon Skeet.

Comment: Thanks Jim, at least I understand how it happened (although I'm not entirely sure why anyone would care that much...)